# Model undefined when creating using modular javascript

Tags: jquery, model-view-controller, modular

Here is my code. I am trying to learn javascript modular pattern and implement mvc using that. I am abeginner in javascript. I have a form with fields where i want to write to log on button click. I always get the model undefined when i do this. where am i getting this wrong. Please help and thanks in advance

```
   var SPModel = {
        caseModel : {
            caseno : $('#txtCaseNo').val(),
            caseSubmittedBy : $('#txtCaseUserName').val(),
            caseEmail : $('#txtCaseUserEmail').val(),
            caseMessage : $('#txtCaseMessage').val()
        }
    };

    var SPView = {
        AddCaseDetailsView : function (model) {

            console.log('Set view using model data');
            console.log(model.caseno);
            console.log(model);

        }
    };

    var SPController = {

        AddCaseDetails : function () {
            console.log(' Controller Calling Model');
            SPView.AddCaseDetailsView(SPModel.caseModel);
        }

    };

    var BindEvents = function () {
        $("#btnSubmitMessage").click(SPController.AddCaseDetails);
    };

    $(document).ready(function () {
        BindEvents();
    });
```